# What's a clean way to switch from parallel to sequential evaluation?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

In a divide-and-conquer algorithm, it makes sense to send the divided problem pieces to separate threads if

1. Each piece is large enough and
2. There aren't terribly many threads running yet.

Simple example: in merge sort, given a 50,000,000 element list, it makes sense to send the first half to one thread and the second to another, and so on a few times, but at some point (probably after at most four splits on a typical PC, I would imagine), the threading overhead overtakes any gains. What's the best way to write the code to make the transition from splitting threads to not doing so?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing could be solved by using Java's Fork/Join Framework. [Here is an example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/java-mergesort-using-forkjoin-framework.html). ForkJoinPool would not produce many threads, but rather reuse them while some are waiting. FJP was created exactly for solving devide and conquere problems.

Answer (score 0):

"it makes sense to send the first half to one thread and the second to another" - no, because exact time of each thread can vary. As a result, one thread finishes and second continue alone, thus reducing parallelism.

So requirements are:

1. Each piece is large enough and there are many of them, to keep balance of processor's payload
2. There aren't terribly many threads running yet, because many threads only consume memory and do not improve performance.

As a result, number of pieces of work != number of threads. This means that a thread pool should be used. Splitting work into pieces is independent of choosing the the size of thread pool. The larger a piece, the less switching, but less balancing. As a rule of thumb, there should be >100 pieces, each executing from 1 to 1000 milliseconds. The side of thread pool is the number of available processors, multiplied by some factor if works do I/O.